# Вызов метода при создании экземпляра класса

Tags: php, ооп

меня интересует следующий момент, я могу вызвать метод сразу после создания экземпляра класса таким образом:

```
(new Class)->method()
```

никак не могу найти подробное описание такого способа, чем плох, чем хорош? И почему, мы сначала вызываем метод, а только потом создаем экземпляр? или создание экземпляра в скобках по другому интерпретируется? Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: в каком месте вы тут видите сначала вызова, потом создание, вы код читаете справа налево что ли?

Answer (score 1):

[Ответ на английском на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402505/in-php-can-you-instantiate-an-object-and-call-a-method-on-the-same-line).

> Запрашиваемая вами функция доступна в PHP 5.4. Вот список новых функций в PHP 5.4:
>   https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration54.new-features.php
>   И соответствующая часть из списка новых функций:
>   Добавлена возможность получения доступа к члену класса при создании экземпляра. Например: (new Foo)->bar().

От себя могу только добавить, что такая нотация используется когда нас не интересует сам объект, а требуется только вызвать его метод. В `(new Class)` мы создаем экземпяр объекта, как обычно. А поскольку нас интересует **только** результат выполнения метода, мы вызываем метод этого объекта `->method()`.

Пример использования:

```php
$formattedDate = (new DateTime($timestamp, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow')))
                 ->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: спасибо, но меня больше интересовали плюсы такого вызова, например, как влияет на память, быстродействие, имеет ли смысл в большом стеке вызовов разных функций использовать этот метод или лучше записать в переменную этот экземпляр и уже оттуда вызывать...

Comment: На память влияет положительно - поскольку на объект после использования нет ссылок, память может быть утилизирована сборщиком мусора в любой момент. На быстродействие тоже влияет положительно. Сейчас цифры не приведу, но было дело - поменял операции в цикле на 1000 итераций использование с такого на переменные - и время выполнения скрипта выросло на несколько процентов. Можете проверить сами, проведя простейшие тесты.